# nfcpy: How to get on-release event correctly with NFCPY?

Tags: python, nfc, rfid

I try to listen to different RFID ID cards with a ACR122 reader and the [nfcpy](https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) python library.

I would like to have the card's ID when the user connect it (without recognized it over and over) and get an event when user release it. Ideally in a loop, in order to listen to the next card when the user take his card away.

Below is my code, but the `on-release` event is fired even if the card is still on the reader. What is the correct way to

1. Get `on-connect` without recognizing over and over ?
2. Get `on-release` when user the card is away ?

```
    import nfc

    def on_startup(targets):
      return targets

    def on_connect(tag):
      uid = str(tag.identifier).encode("hex").upper()
      print(uid)
      return True

    def on_release(tag):
      print('Released')
      return tag

    rdwr_options = {
      'on-startup': on_startup,
      'on-connect': on_connect,
      'on-release': on_release,
      'beep-on-connect': False,
    }

    with nfc.ContactlessFrontend('usb') as clf:
      tag = clf.connect(rdwr=rdwr_options)
```

Comment: Could you come up with a solution to this, in the meantime? Would be highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

You might need to set an interval in your `ContactlessFrontend` config. Try this example:

```
import nfc
import ndef

tags = set()

rec = ndef.UriRecord("https://google.com")

def on_connect(tag):
    if tag.identifier not in tags:

        tags.add(tag.identifier)
        fmt = tag.format()

        if fmt is None:
            print("Tag cannot be formatted (not supported).")
        elif fmt is False:
            print("Tag failed to be formatted (for some reason).")
        else:
            tag.ndef.records = [rec]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    clf = nfc.ContactlessFrontend()
    if not clf.open('usb'):
        raise RuntimeError("Failed to open NFC device.")

    while True:
        config = {
            'interval': 0.35,
            'on-connect': on_connect
        }
        ret = clf.connect(rdwr=config)
        if ret is None:
            pass
        elif not ret:
            print ("NFC connection terminated due to an exception.")
            break
        else:
            pass
    clf.close()
```

https://gist.github.com/henrycjc/c1632b2d1f210ae0ff33d860c7c2eb8f

Comment: Thanks, but how to trigger 'on-release' when the card is released for the NFC reader ? Do you have an idea?

Comment: @RenaudKern read the documentation here https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/clf.html in addition to providing the `on-connect` function, you can also provide a function that takes `tag` as its only positional argument for `on-release`.

Comment: @henrycjc "you can also provide a function [...] for `on-release`" > This is exactly what OP has in his snippet, no? I think the problem of OP is that `nfcpy` calls the `on-release` function immediately after the `on-connect` with the card still on the reader (thus, physically connected, not released). Having the same problem here. The docs do, in my opinion, not really clarify how to circumvent this.

Answer (score 0):

[This discussion](https://answers.launchpad.net/nfcpy/+question/617298) helped me figuring out how to solve this.

When reading [the docs (`‘on-release’ : function(tag)`)](https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/clf.html?highlight=sense#contactless-frontend) very carefully – yes, it took me some loops – it becomes apparent that `on-release` is called as soon as `on-connect` returns `True`.

> **This function is called when** the presence check was run (**the ‘on-connect’ function returned a true value**) and determined that communication with the tag has become impossible, or when the ‘terminate’ function returned a true value. The tag object may be used for cleanup actions but not for communication.

It seems that `on-release` must not be understood in a physical way, but rather in a communicative way (Released from communications, you may now remove the card).

To solve this issue, one needs to determine whether a card is present after it connected (or more precisely, after it was released – more about that later). The following code does the trick:

```py
import nfc
import time
import logging
import inspect

logging.basicConfig(format="[%(name)s:%(levelname).4s] %(message)s")

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def on_startup(targets):
    logger.debug(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)
    for target in targets:
        target.sensf_req = bytearray.fromhex("0012FC0000")
    return targets


def on_discover(target):
    logger.debug(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)
    logger.info(target)
    return True


def on_connect(tag):
    logger.debug(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)
    logger.info(tag)
    return True


def on_release(tag):
    logger.debug(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)
    # Loop while card is present
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if not clf.sense(*[nfc.clf.RemoteTarget(target) for target in rdwr_options["targets"]]):
            logger.info("Card removed")
            break
    return True


rdwr_options = {
    "targets": ("106A", "106B", "212F"),
    "on-startup": on_startup,
    "on-discover": on_discover,  # Here just for completeness :)
    "on-connect": on_connect,
    "on-release": on_release,
}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.debug(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)
    with nfc.ContactlessFrontend() as clf:
        if not clf.open("usb"):
            raise RuntimeError("Failed to open NFC device.")

        while True:
            ret = clf.connect(rdwr=rdwr_options)
            if not ret:
                break
```

Now is later: If we wait for removal of the card during the `on-connect` state, we run into trouble as `on-release` expects to retrieve information from the card (`tag` argument), which it cannot get anymore as communication is not possible with the card removed.

PS: The above mentioned discussion reads that the behavior of `on-release` depends on the type of card one is using.

> So, I have a need to register when a card is present and when it leaves again. I have some Type2 tags for this.
>
> Given this code:
>
> ```py
> def connected(tag):
>     print(tag)
>     return True def released(tag):
>     print("Bye")
>
> tag = clf.connect(rdwr={'on-connect': connected, 'on-release':
> released})
> ```
>
> I would expect it to echo out the Tag ID when I present it to the
> reader, and the echo "Bye" once I remove it. This works as expected on
> a Type4 tag I have..

> I'm afraid those cards are Mifare Classic 1K not supported by nfcpy. It is possible to read the UID but any other command requires to first authenticate and use the Mifare Crypto scheme. This should be doable with NXP reader ICs [...]. And NXP has a good selection of NFC Forum compatible Type 2 Tags that work just great.